Global error handling in MAUI app, still not possible?
I have a Xamarin Forms application I have converted to Maui. The app only targets Windows and Android. Previously, when an error occurred, in the platform specific code, I displayed the error details (using MessageDialog in UWP, and using an AlertDialog in Android).
I was hoping, in 2024, that Maui had matured to have superior implementation of error handling than Xamarin had - but actually it feels like a step backwards.
I have an error in my code, which for some reason does not get picked up by handling AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException. It does, however, get picked up if in the Windows specific code in the App class write a handler for UnhandledException. In the handler, I would like to display the error, and then quit.
But if I use MessageDialog I get an Invalid Window Handle exception... so how can I display the error details?
And also, how can I reliably quit the application? I would rather do that than let the application carry on in an unknown state. And no, I don't want to wrap every method in a try... catch!
Note I am not using Shell.

You can refer to this and try to  use   Application.Current.Quit  to quit the application .
